# Google map marker not in correct position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

- I follow this example to do this tutorial. Below is the link: (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration)
- I have 4 places and their latitude and longitude: 
  -> Westminster Bridge [51.5018457,-0.1225088]
  -> Big Ben [51.5031154,-0.1207032]
  -> London Eye  [51.503773,-0.1224413]
  -> Hungerford Bridge and Golden Jubilee Bridges [51.503773,-0.1224413]

Here is the code that I written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);

var neighborhoods = [
   new google.maps.LatLng(51.504728,-0.1216795),
   new google.maps.LatLng(51.5031154,-0.1207032),
   new google.maps.LatLng(51.5018457,-0.1225088),
   new google.maps.LatLng(51.503773,-0.1224413)
];

var markers = [];
var map;

function initialize() 
{
   var mapProp = 
   {
      center: myCenter,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
   };

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapProp);
}

function drop() 
{
   clearMarkers();

   for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) 
   {
       addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);
   }
}

function clearMarkers() 
{
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
   {
       markers[i].setMap(null);
   }

   markers = [];
}

function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) 
{
   window.setTimeout(function() 
   {
       markers.push(new google.maps.Marker
       ({
           position: position,
           map: map,
           animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
       }));
   }, timeout);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="panel">
   <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>
</div>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:800px;height:600px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

- When I run the above code, all marker is not in correct position as shown as image below:
  [image]
- Am I writing the wrong code?

Comment: Please check again this position: 'new google.maps.LatLng(51.5031154,-0.1207032),'. 
I had check it on Google map and it point to near
London Eye Pier

Comment: @MrNeo zoom in/out will affect the latitude and longitude value?

Comment: I don't think zoom in/out could affect the value @@.

Comment: @MrNeo Ok. I will just focus on the latitude and longitude value for each place. And a thanks for you.

Comment: The coordinates in your code and the coordinates in the list in your question are different.

Answer (score 1):

Your values are wrong see the map for an example https://www.google.com/maps/place/51%C2%B030'17.0%22N+0%C2%B007'18.1%22W/@51.504728,-0.1216795,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0

I don't know what you are trying to point at but it is pointing exactly where you are asking it too.